# MySQL PHP adding 3306 without my input

Tags: php, mysql, linux, cron

I have a back end cron script that checks MySQl regurlarly for an if-then condition and then runs a Curl action. Anyway, the script has been running fine for over a year now when suddenly a problem occured and it does not make sense to me

here is the truncated code for the script

```
<?php
    //assign values to variables
    $servername = "localhost:3306";

    $username = "username";

    $password = "password";

    $database = "database";

    $con = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $results = "SELECT NewUserID FROM queue ORDER BY ID";

    $queryresults = $con->query($results);

    if($con->error) {
        printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $con->error);
        die();
    }
```

I would see this error:

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Failed to parse address "localhost:3306:3306" in /home/foo/bar/BackEnd.php on line 11
Failed to connect to MySQL: Failed to parse address "localhost:3306:3306"
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on boolean in /home/foo/bar/BackEnd.php:19
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
thrown in /home/foo/bar/BackEnd.php on line 19
```

The solution was simple, I change "localhost:3306" to "localhost" and everything worked again, since it seemed that ":3306" was being added to what was already there. This solution seems like a problem waiting to happen but im not sure what went wrong in the first place. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't specify the port in the `host` parameter.
Here is the full function definition:

```
mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbname, $port, $socket);
```

You should just add the port at the end of your call. Like this:

```
$con = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database, 3306);
```

Comment: Any Idea on why it went so long without causing an error? I guess computers are funny like that yet it just seems odd to have the problem surface now. also the default is 3306, correct? if the parameter is let blank.

Comment: yes `3306` is the default MySQL port. You can just omit it and use `localhost` w/o any port. I don't know why it used to work before, maybe you've got PHP version updated recently?

Comment: You were absolutely right, my web-host updated to php 7 finally and I guess this was a side effect. Thanks for the help!